# Pre-selecting value on edit page with blade in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have an issue where i want to show the current brand in a select, on the edit page of a vehicle mode.
The select has to contain all the brands, so it is possible to choose another brand on editing the model.

I have this in my vehicleModelsController edit:

```
$vehicle_brands = VehicleBrand::all();
        $selected_vehicle_brand = VehicleBrand::first()->vehicle_brand_id;

        return view('vehicleModels.edit', compact(['vehicleModel', 'vehicle_brands'], ['selected_vehicle_brand']));
```

And in my edit.blade file i have the following select:

```php
<select class="form-control" name="vehicle_brand_id">
    @if ($vehicle_brands->count())
        @foreach($vehicle_brands as $vehicle_brand)
            <option value="{{ $vehicle_brand->id }}" {{ $selected_vehicle_brand == $vehicle_brand->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>
                {{ $vehicle_brand->brand }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endif
</select>
```

And it works just fine with editing, but it does not show the current value as selected, it shows the first value in the brand table.

I have Brand1, Brand2, Brand3 and Brand4 as test values in the brand table, but no matter what brand the model is related to, it shows Brand1 in the select on the edit page.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller you are assigning value of `VehicleBrand::first()->vehicle_brand_id` to `$selected_vehicle_brand` and then you are comparing it with `id` field in `{{ $selected_vehicle_brand == $vehicle_brand->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}`

If there is not column/field named `vehicle_brand_id` on `VehicleBrand` model then `VehicleBrand::first()->vehicle_brand_id` will be `null`. So when you compare `$selected_vehicle_brand == $vehicle_brand_id` it will be like `null == $vehicle_brand->id` which will be false for any id value.

So it should either be (in Controller)

```php
$selected_vehicle_brand = VehicleBrand::first()->id;
//Here we are hard coding the value to be the id of first record of VehicleBrand
//However in practice it should come from either request/route param eg: $id received via the request/route param
//Or from VehicleModel being edited eg: $vehicleModel->vehicle_brand->id
```

And `{{ $selected_vehicle_brand == $vehicle_brand->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}` in the view

Or, if `vehicle_brand_id` column/field exists on `VehicleBrand`, it should be (in Controller)

```php
$selected_vehicle_brand = VehicleBrand::first()->vehicle_brand_id;
```

and `{{ $selected_vehicle_brand == $vehicle_brand->vehicle_brand_id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}`

The field you are comparing the values for should be the same.

And as a side note, if you are on Laravel 9 you can use `@selected` blade directive
`@selected(old($vehicle_brand->id) == $selected_vehicle_brand)`

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!
my vehicle_brand table id is just called id, so i have changed the controller to "$selected_vehicle_brand = VehicleBrand::first()->id;" and the  edit.blade.php select to: "<option value="{{ $vehicle_brand->id }}" {{ $selected_vehicle_brand == $vehicle_brand->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>
                                    {{ $vehicle_brand->brand }}</option>", also tried with the Laravel 9 option @select that you kindly sendt me, but i am still getting first value of brand in the select on the edit page. So that means i am still hitting null? tried both

Comment: You are getting the first option as selected as you are assigning `id` of first record of `VehicleBrands` to `$selected_vehicle_brand`. If you do `$selected_vehicle_brand = VehicleBrand::find($id)->id;` where `$id` is dynamic - comes from request/route parameter or from `$vehicleModel->vehicle_brand` then it will show the selected accordingly. You can try `$selected_vehicle_brand = VehicleBrand::find(2)->id` in controller to check if 2nd option in select list is shown as selected. Currently you are hard coding `id` of the first record, so it always shows 1st option as selected.